# Batch variable unable to hold full text file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file that will remove some special characters from a .txt file and append it to another file but the variable is unable to hold the full 1 million++ words in the text file.

Is there any way to make the variable hold all the words or at least split it into groups/sets?

The text look like this

```
{"One:1","two:2","three:4","four:3","five:5","EG:[512]","sets:{559,212,333,940}"};{"One:9","two:3","three:2","four:1","five:6","EG:[513]","sets:{551,215,331,944}"};...
```

So far I have tried using a FOR loop to append it to many different files then go through each files later using goto but it just doesn't work like it should.

Comment: Looks like a JSON array.  You might parse it with Javascript, if you're on windows use CSCRIPT.exe

Comment: good idea but sadly I am not allowed to use anything other than batch to do this operation.

Comment: What special characters are you removing?

Comment: oh, the character removing part removes all characters except " which is already done, just looking for a way to make the 1 million word fit in the variable so that it can be processed.

Comment: You're probably out of luck for a pure batch solution because there's a line-length limit of 8 KB and it looks like your input file is one gigantic line.

Comment: would it be possible to break it down then?

Comment: Are you trying to remove all the characters and only keep the quotes?

Answer (score 1):

**edited** - Previous answer at the bottom. As jeb comments this is faster, not sure if it will even be usable but faster (but, of course, being faster than the previous code is an easy task)

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    <"in.txt" >"out.txt" call :process
    goto :Eof

:process
    set /p "buffer=" || goto :eof
    set "buffer=%buffer:"=%"
    set "buffer=%buffer:,= %"
    set "buffer=%buffer:{=%"
    set "buffer=%buffer:}=%"
    set "buffer=%buffer:[=%"
    set "buffer=%buffer:]=%"
    set "buffer=%buffer:;=%"
    set "buffer=%buffer::=%"
    set "buffer=%buffer:0=%"
    set "buffer=%buffer:1=%"
    set "buffer=%buffer:2=%"
    set "buffer=%buffer:3=%"
    set "buffer=%buffer:4=%"
    set "buffer=%buffer:5=%"
    set "buffer=%buffer:6=%"
    set "buffer=%buffer:7=%"
    set "buffer=%buffer:8=%"
    set "buffer=%buffer:9=%"

    <nul set /p "=%buffer%"
    goto :process
```

---

**WARNING** : This should not have ever been written. IT IS PAINFULLY SLOW.

Once it has been said,

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem File configuration
    set "inputFile=data.txt"
    set "outputFile=out.txt"

    rem Variable to hold a cariage return used to show that the 
    rem script is still working
    set "CR="
    for /f %%c in ('copy /Z "%~f0" nul') do if not defined "CR" set "CR=%%c"

    rem A temporary file will be used.
    for %%t in ("%temp%\%~nx0.%random%%random%.tmp") do (

        echo Splitting input file into temporary file
        > "%%~ft" (
            (   %= Split the input file into one character per line =%
                cmd /u /q /c"type ""%inputFile%""" | cmd /a /q /c"find /v "" " 
                %= Ensure we have a terminator to empty buffer (keep reading...) =%
                <nul set /p"=;"

            )|( %= Remove non needed characters =%
                findstr /i /r /c:"^[a-z,;]"
            )
        ) 
        echo Splitting done

        echo Starting to read temporary file
        echo %time% Here we go ...
        set "buffer=@"
        rem All data to stdout will be placed into the output file
        > "%outputFile%" (
            for /f usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%a in ("%%~ft") do (

                rem Concatenate one character to the buffer
                setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
                for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%b in ("!buffer!") do (
                    endlocal
                    set "buffer=%%b%%a"
                )

                rem We will use the semicolon as a delimiter to do 
                rem partial processing of the input data
                if "%%a"==";" (

                    rem Execute the required processing on the buffer
                    call :processSection buffer

                    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
                    < nul (
                        rem Write the processed buffer to stdout
                        set /p "=!buffer!"
                        rem Show we are still working
                        >con set /p "=!time! ... still working ... !CR!"
                    )
                    endlocal

                    set "buffer=@"
                )
            )
        )
        rem Processed temporary file can be removed
    ) & del "%%~ft"

    echo(
    echo %time% ... Done
    goto :eof


:processSection varName
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Retrieve the data from the indicated variable
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%a in ("!%~1!") do (
        endlocal 
        set "line=%%a"
    )
    rem The passed buffer includes an initial filler character
    set "line=%line:~1%"

    rem Process buffer
    set "line=%line:,= %"
    set "line=%line:;= %"
    set "line=%line:  = %"

    rem Return buffer to the caller
    endlocal & set "%~1=%line%"
    goto :eof
```

It was written just for testing but, please, use any other thing.

Comment: Cool idea! But it's really really slow. Perhaps splitting with `set/p` could be faster

Comment: @jeb, i had to leave it for a later edition but here it is. *"... could be faster"*, NO, **It is faster**. ANYTHING is faster than the previous code (but I'm sure I will never use something like any of both codes in a production system to handle an input file as described). I wrote the previous code just to test if the partial character removal in the `findstr` could make it behave better.

Comment: how the hell does this work? Isn't `set /p` supposed to read whole lines? How does it split and how does it know where to start the next read?

Comment: @Stephan, `set /p` reads until it founds the end of file, the end of a line or until its buffer (1023 characters plus ending nul) is full, whatever happens first. But after a read, the file pointer is after the last readed position. A new read over the same redirection will return the next set of characters.

Comment: Thank you, MC. I was sure, there is a buffersize but am surprised about the existence of a pointer. Looks as some developer had a good idea.